# LINQ - How to select with subquery

Tags: linq

My data is:

```
+-----+--------+-----------+
| Id  |  Name  |  ParentId |
+-----+--------+-----------+    
|  1  |   A    |     0     |
|  2  |   B    |     0     |
|  3  |   C    |     1     |
+-----+--------+-----------+
```

How do I get `C` if we have `ParentId = 0` by LINQ?

Comment: `.Where(x => x.ParentId != 0)`?  Heck, `.Last()` will work in your sample set.  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: I want to use subquery. Because .Where(x => x.ParentId != 0) is not ok. If we have another record with parentId = 2, we can not get C

Comment: Then how do you *identify* the record(s) that you want?  Nobody here can answer that for you, that's a matter for the logic of the system you're building.  Once you have a means to identify what you're looking for, you have a clause on which to filter data.  The statement "use a subquery" by itself sounds like an attempt to cast a spell to get the data you want.  It's meaningless without any way to logically identify that data.

Comment: T-SQL is select * from Category where ParentId in (select CateId from Category where ParentId = 0). I want to change it to LinQ

Comment: What is the collection you're querying with LINQ?  Rows in a `DataTable`?  An `IEnumerable<>` of in-memory objects?  LINQ to SQL?  LINQ to Entities?  Do those objects have navigation properties following this `ParentId` key relationship?  If they don't, *can* they?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Categories" is the collection name, I think this is what you need.

```
var parentCategoryIds = Collections.Where(c => c.ParentId == 0).Select(c => c.Id);

var results = Collections.Where(c => parentCategoryIds.Contains(c.ParentId));
```

And if you want to get the name, you can do

```
var names = results.Select(r => r.Name);
```

These three statements could be written into one linq statement but I did this for clarity.